# First post questions: Good reviewing practice

Tags: discussion, etiquette, review-page

In light of related questions [Is the "First Posts" review queue partially broken?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3390/15717) and 
[First Post review process broken](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3553/15717). As suggested by [Charles Stewart and mafp](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3554/15717).

I am listing out some ideas on *first post review check list* just for record and additions if any are welcome

#### Content checklist

To ensure the question is put together well, there are several points to check:

- **Good (Sharp/Specific) Title**: Reflecting the exact Q with hints from [Meta

  question by Marc Van Dongen](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128/15717). Look at this stage for basic typos/spelling mistakes.
- **Perfect Tagging**: Tagging relevant tags for Q. (more (2–5) specific tags are better to narrow down the track down required question for future users instead of generic `pdftex` tag for all Q)
- Is a **Minimal Working Example** [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) needed?  See [Are there questions where we can recognize that a MWE is not necessary?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3386/15717)
- **Code markup**/formatting ok to improve readability using [editing help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
- Adding **images/codes from external links** in Q to make OP's question standalone as Question have backup/revision control and external links may fail over time.
- Is the question incomplete because of **key information only given in comments**? Editing these into the question text makes it easier to grasp what is needed, and helps the process of narrowing down requirements because comments don't have backup/revision control. ***Important Edit Note:*** Write down the modifications for eg: "codemarkup+title changed as per OP's comments+MWE/images added from Dropbox link+Spelling/Typo correction". This edit note sentences help high rep reviewers to accept/reject the suggested edits. **Attention :** Editing Q only when really necessary not editing for sake of editing, and the reason for major editing has to be mentioned to OP through comments/edit notes.

Ensuring that these points are followed not only helps that question find answers, it also helps communicate the standards we want the site to follow to new users.

#### General guidelines

- **Be Kind**: Reviewing/editing Q to improve OP's chances of getting a good answer and increase readability for readers and accumulating as good knowledge base and much more..
- Leave Welcome **comments with starter guide, MWE request,** tips to OP to learn code markup and other specific actions based on [Text Building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/15717)
- In case interested leaving duplicates/related questions based on [advanced search at tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=#)
- **Don't forget the Mantra Upvote Q immediately and often, Downvote with comments and Accept answer later (24hrs).**
- Related terminology used in tex.sx/meta: [Dictionary: Commonly Used English Acronyms and abbreviations at TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3388/15717) and Finally never despair everyone makes mistakes and remember learning from them.

In case I forgot anything please add to this list and any duplicate/related questions in meta are also welcome.

Comment: A bit nebulous, but I think it's important to **be kind**. Which doesn't mean not editing (quite the reverse), but the spirit should be "Interesting question; to improve your chances of getting a good answer and to conform to our habits here, I've made a few changes" not "Ugh! Newbie! You are busted! You got this wrong, and this, and this. Read all these faqs to find out how not to embarrass yourself again."  Adding "welcome" to a message like that doesn't make it welcoming.